# HTML5 - header and the outline algorithm - confusion

Tags: html

I was just reading the HTML5 spec again to find out if I can nest a `nav` element inside a `header`. The paragraph for the `header` element is *a bit* strange if you ask me, but probably only because I don't understand it.

> In this example, the page has a page heading given by the h1 element,
>   and two subsections whose headings are given by h2 elements. The
>   content after the header element is still part of the last subsection
>   started in the header element, because the header element doesn't take
>   part in the outline algorithm.

```
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Little Green Guys With Guns</h1>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/games">Games</a>
    <li><a href="/forum">Forum</a>
    <li><a href="/download">Download</a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <h2>Important News</h2> <!-- this starts a second subsection -->
  <!-- this is part of the subsection entitled "Important News" -->
  <p>To play today's games you will need to update your client.</p>
  <h2>Games</h2> <!-- this starts a third subsection -->
 </header>
 <p>You have three active games:</p>
 <!-- this is still part of the subsection entitled "Games" -->
 ...
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element

So, according to the comment, `<p>You have three active games:</p>` is still part of the subsection that started inside the header because the header by itself does not introduce a new section.

But doesn't this break with the nesting structure that HTML is build on? For example, this is invalid markup because the nesting is wrong:

```
<div>
    <p>
</div>
</p>
```

But If I would define - theoretically - that the div does not do anything, then it would be fine?

Please don't get me wrong, this is not a rant or anything, I just try to understand whats the sense behind this? Also, why is the header element listed under sections, if its not a sectioning element?

By the way, is HTML5 outlining still as broken as it was about a year ago? Or is there a tool or something that handles it correct by now?

Answer (score 0):

> So, according to the comment,
>
> You have three active games:
>
> is
>   still part of the subsection.

Keyword here is according to the comment, which is not the code. Technically the paragraph is a child of the body. I'ld agree the coding and comments do not match, but the code is technically not incorrect. And there are no restrictions that comments or content can only exist in one block.

This

```
<div>
    <p>
</div>
</p>
```

is technically incorrect which you can see more clearly if I add some CSS.

```
div { height:100px; width:auto; }
p {display:block; height:50px; width:300px}
```

Given that CSS what is the above code suppose to look like?

What compatible browsers may do is rewrite the above code into

```
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>
<p></p>
```

After the browser engine rewrite the HTML and CSS can be rendered.